# How to read from bigquery in a streaming pipeline written using apache beam

Tags: google-bigquery, google-cloud-dataflow, apache-beam

I want to run a streaming pipeline that reads continuously from a Google bigquery table. Right now my streaming pipeline stops after reading from the bigquery table once. The apache beam [documentation](https://beam.apache.org/documentation/io/built-in/google-bigquery/) doesn't seem to mention about it.

Please help

Design is

I have a base table that has list of users (information like username, id, date of birth). This table gets modified once in every 12 hrs. I want to run a pipeline which takes this table as input and finds the total number of unique users. So instead of running a batch pipeline every 12 hrs on the entire base table, I thought of a streaming pipeline that constantly reads from the base table, has a global window along with a repeated trigger for every 12 hrs to output the unique users count

Comment: You need something to till apache-beam to re-read the data from BigQuery... what is your pipeline design?

Comment: +1, Beam reads the entire table and shuts down (batch workload). You probably have to use some intermediary messaging such as Pub/Sub to achieve what you want. A description of the design/intent would be helpful.

Comment: @BrunoVolpato

I have added the design of my pipeline, please can you help

Comment: Have you been able to fix this?